# Return a comma separated list of strings from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to return a comma separated list of strings from a stored procedure like this:

```
@Strings NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT

...

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = 'SELECT @Strings = COALESCE(@Strings + '', '','''') + CAST(Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM ' + @BlaTableName + ' order by Name'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

but I get:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Strings"

Any ideas?

Comment: `@Strings` is out of scope within the context of `sp_executesql`

Comment: fwiw, you'll get better results by returning a set and creating the comma-separated list in the client app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Sql has its own scope, any variables declared outside of its scope are not visible to dynamic sql, You declare any passing variable in second parameter to `sp_executesql` and if you are expecting to store and retrieve a value from that variable pass it as an `OUTPUT` variable using the key work `OUT` or `OUTPUT`.

Also use `QUOTENAME()` function around your Sql Server Object names when concatenating them into strings. Protects you against sql injection attack.

See below....

```
DECLARE @Strings NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @BlaTableName NVARCHAR(128) = N'Table_Name'

SET @Sql = N'SELECT @Strings = COALESCE(@Strings + '','', '''','''') + CAST(Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@BlaTableName) + N' order by Name'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
                  ,N'@Strings NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT' --<-- you need to declare variable here
                  ,@Strings OUTPUT

SELECT @Strings   --<-- Test it
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use FOR XML PATH method for concatenating string,

Second, you need an OUTPUT parameter to make this work:

```
declare @strings nvarchar(max)
declare @BlaTableName  sysname = 'customer';

declare @Sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
select @strings=substring(col_list, 1, len(col_list)-1)
from (
    select column_name + '', '' as [text()]
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = ''' + @BlaTableName + '''
    order by ordinal_position
    for xml path('''')) x(col_list)
'

exec sp_executesql
@sql,
N'@strings nvarchar(max) out',
@strings out

select @strings
```

This is using AdventureWorks2012 sample database, modify to your schema.